# Connecting PayPal sandbox account REST API

Tags: php, rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to create an invoice using PayPal's REST API but I am getting an authentication error. I know that means my credentials are not correct but the thing is my credentials are correct, I am 100% sure. I tried creating new sandbox account and entered new details but I still receive the same error. I am pasting the code, please have a look and suggest to me what's wrong.

```
Array
(
    [Errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Receiver] => 
                    [Category] => Application
                    [Domain] => PLATFORM
                    [ErrorID] => 520003
                    [ExceptionID] => 
                    [Message] => Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.
                    [Parameter] => 
                    [Severity] => Error
                    [Subdomain] => Application
                )

        )

    [Ack] => Failure
    [Build] => 10835894
    [CorrelationID] => f0f2e4987adcd
    [Timestamp] => 2014-05-08T05:56:10.442-07:00
    [InvoiceID] => 
    [InvoiceNumber] => 
    [InvoiceURL] => 
    [XMLRequest] => ReturnAllen_US
AngellEYE_PHPClass
    [XMLResponse] => 2014-05-08T05:56:10.442-07:00Failuref0f2e4987adcd10835894520003PLATFORMApplicationErrorApplicationAuthentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are very few things that would result in that error code.  The obvious, incorrect or mistyped credentials being passed.  The less obvious, passing live site credentials to a test endpoint, or passing test credentials to a live endpoint.

You stated you are using Sandbox credentials, so you need to be sure you are passing to the REST test endpoint. (https://api.sandbox.paypal.com for test mode, or https://api.paypal.com  for live)

Comment: Hey i have an app under REST Apps in my account, what credentials i use? the one we get from Profile->My selling tools->API access or the one one we get by clicking on the application created under REST apps in developer account?

Comment: Rajesh if this is concerning an application that you're developing you'll likely use those, but I would contact our technical department at paypal.com/mts first to ensure that is the case.